# Flat List<T> to structured List<T> via recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

I have an existing class :

```
public class Product
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int ParentId { get; set; }
 public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have a given `List<Product>`:

```
var Lst = new List<Product>();
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=1,ParentId=0,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=2,ParentId=0,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=3,ParentId=0,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=60,ParentId=1,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=61,ParentId=1,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=62,ParentId=61,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=72,ParentId=61,Info="a"});
Lst.Add(new Product{ Id=90,ParentId=2,Info="a"});
```

Visualization :

```
1
|
+---60
|
+---61
     |
     +---62
     |
     +---72

2
|
+---90

3
```

As you can see ,  the `List<>`  is *flat*. (all items are in the same level within the list. it's just that the `id,parentId` represents heirarchy)

Now - I need to create structural `List<>` so each item in `List` will be *inside* its parent object :

so I created an additional structure class  which will hold this structure :

```
public class Node
{
 public Product Product { get; set; }
 public List<Node> LstNodes  { get; set; }
}
```

So now I can do :

```
List<Node> lstNodes = new List<Node>();
```

And initially I can add the root ones :

```
lstNodes=Lst.Where(product=>product.ParentId==0).Select(node=>new Node{Product=node}).ToList();
```

And now I can start recursion to insert items with their parents.

*So Where is the problem ?*

**Question:**

I want to avoid insertion of root elements first ( root is where `ParentId=0`).

Is there any way of doing this with *one* recursive method (including roots) ?

Desired result : 3 nodes in `lstNodes` where each has its children recursively.

Comment: you can do this in a declerative style if you pass a dictionary with Id->Node around to link the children to their parents. But in this case I would just do this in an old fashioned `foreach` loop style ;) - btw: the list should be sorted for Id to make this quite easy but it seems to already be

Comment: I honestly can't figure out how to do this recursively...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List<Node> GetNodes(List<Product> lst, int parentId = 0)
{
    var childProducts = lst.Where(x=>x.ParentId == parentId);
    return childProducts
           .Select(x=> new Node { Product = x, LstNodes = GetNodes(lst, x.Id)}
           .ToList();
}
```

And purely generic version:

```
class Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public List<Node<T>> LstNodes  { get; set; }
}

List<Node<T>> GetNodes<T>(List<T> lst, Func<T, int> idSelector, Func<T, int> parentIdSelector, int parentId = 0)
{
    var childProducts = lst.Where(x=>parentIdSelector(x) == parentId);
    return childProducts
           .Select(x=> new Node<T> { Item = x, LstNodes = GetNodes<T>(lst, idSelector,parentIdSelector, idSelector(x))})
           .ToList();
}

GetNodes(Lst,x=>x.Id,x=>x.ParentId, 0);
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yeah, it is missing the generic parameter. Fixed my code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yeah. Sorry. Didn't really bother running it through VS.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I went by your requirement to use recursion. Look at 3dGrabber's answer for better solution. I'm not sure if it is possible to make better recursive solution.

Comment: Yes I know :-) Just thinking to myself if it possible still using recursion but to reduce on(2).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    static List<Node> BuildTree(List<Product> lst, int topID) 
    {
        var tree = Enumerable.Empty<Node>().ToList();
        if (lst == null)
        {
            return tree;
        }

        foreach (var product in lst)
        {
            if (product.ParentId == topID)
            {
                Node node = new Node 
                {
                    Product = product,
                    LstNodes = BuildTree(lst.Where(p => p.ParentId == product.Id).ToList(), product.Id)
                };

                tree.Add(node);
            }
        }

        return tree;
    }
```

And you can call: `List<Node> roots = BuildTree(Lst, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

The solutions proposed so far work, but iterate over the entire collection once per node.
This makes them [O(n<sup>2</sup>)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487300/141397) and not suitable for large collections (databases, ...).
Here is a solution running in linear time:

```
var products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(...);
...

var nodes          = products.Select(p => new Node { Product = p }).ToList(); // 1
var nodeWithId     = nodes.ToDictionary(n => n.Product.Id);                   // 2
var parentChildren = nodes.Where(n => n.Product.ParentId != 0)
                          .ToLookup(n => nodeWithId[n.Product.ParentId]);     // 3

foreach (var pc in parentChildren)  // 4
{
    var parent   = pc.Key;
    var children = pc.ToList();

    parent.LstNodes = children;
}
```

Explanation:

1. Create the nodes from the products.
2. Create a dictionary that allows us to easily find a Node with a given id
3. Create a lookup (dictionary with multiple values per key) that gives us the children of a given node.
4. Iterate over the lookup an associate the children with their parents

Comment: Fixed. Forgot about the special case of the root nodes: There is no NodeId 0.